# Modifying parameter's value in consecutive execution of scrollExtend jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Plugin in question - http://contextllc.com/node/51

Hi,

How do I modify parameter's `param` value in the consecutive execution of the below code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend(
            {   
                'target': 'div#scroll_items',           
                'url': 'get_content.php?param=__THIS_CHANGES__', 
                'newElementClass': 'list_item more_content'

            }
        );
    }
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url parameter can actually take a function (or function name - without parentheses) as well as a string. So, Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend(
            {   
                'target': 'div#scroll_items',           
                'url': function() {
                      //code to get the URL goes here
                },
                'newElementClass': 'list_item more_content'

            }
        );
    }
);
```